# Delete specific value in recordset, Not whole record

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to delete one value in a found recordset, not the whole record. 
In this instance I want to delete:

```
 [" & TempVars("Software") & "]='" & TempVars("Version").Value & "'"
```

It finds the record without error. It just deletes the whole record which is not what I want. I just need the software version deleted.

*This is my code:*

```
  Dim rst0 As Recordset
  Set rst0 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SoftwareLicenses", dbOpenDynaset)

  rst0.FindFirst "[SWID] = " & TempVars("SWID").Value & " AND [EmpID] = " & TempVars("EMPID").Value & " AND [SWVersion]= '" & TempVars("Version").Value & "'"

  rst0.Delete
  rst0.Close
  Set rst0 = Nothing


  Dim rst2 As Recordset
  Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("EmpSWDetails", dbOpenDynaset)

  rst2.FindFirst "[EmpID] = " & TempVars("EMPID").Value & " AND [" & TempVars("Software") & "]='" & TempVars("Version").Value & "'"

  rst2.Delete
  rst2.Close
  Set rst2 = Nothing
```

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: I thought may be I'd try using .Edit "rst2! [ & TempVars("Software") & ] = "" but I get an item not in collection error. It doesn't seem to want to take the tempVar in. Even when I converted it to a regular variable it would take it in.

Comment: You can't delete a single field within a record - it doesn't make sense to do so.  Are you wanting to set the field to `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the field value I edited it, declaring the variable in the recordset the correct way.

```
rst2.Edit
rst2.Fields(Software) = ""
```